# Java downcast objects invoking sub method

Tags: java, downcast

The printout is: Fruit
                 Apple
                 Golden
                 Golden

I want to know why the object `c.make()` invokes a method in `class Golden` instead of `class Apple`.Because I think that c is the object of class Apple, where is my mistake? Thanks for your consideration.

```
public class Fruit {
    public Fruit(){
        System.out.println("Fruit");
    }
    public void make(){
        System.out.println("Fruit");
    }

}
class Apple extends Fruit{
    public Apple(){
        System.out.println("Apple");
    }
    public void make(){
        System.out.println("Apple");
    }
}
class Golden extends Apple{
    public Golden(){
        System.out.println("Golden");
    }
    public void make(){
        System.out.println("Golden");
    }
}
public class tet {

        public static void main(String[] args){             
            Fruit b = new Golden();//Fruit Apple Golden
            Apple c = (Apple)b;                                                 
            c.make();               
        }



}
```

Comment: Because even if you cast it to `Apple`, it still is an object of type `Golden`, and since the `make` method is overridden the one inside the `Golden` class gets called.

Comment: What happens in the stack and heap when  (Apple)b shows up? Nothing happens, including the direction of b pointing to the heap?

Comment: To be very Simple **Rule 1** In the heap `object` of that class is created with which you use `new` operator. **Rule 2**  Reference of the class with which you used `new` and all the `classes and interfaces` in the higher hierarchy of that class is only allowed to refer the Object created. *Note*  Referring a Dog by Cat is invalid and referring a dog by animal doesn't take away the capability of barking, its there as its a **dog**. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `c` is the same as `b`. In fact they point to the same exact object, which is of type `Golden`. You just choose to "view" the object through an `Apple` reference, but the actual type doesn't change.

Comment: What happens in the stack and heap when` (Apple)b` shows up? Nothing happens, including the direction of b pointing to the heap?

Comment: You can use `javap` to see the bytecodes generated, but there's nothing very special about using a superclass reference to point to a subclass. Just like you'd write `List<> list = new ArrayList<>();` and you wouldn't expect that you'd suddenly have an instance of the interface `List`.